# Using and writing React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component:

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import useFetch  from "../useFetch";

        export class Patient extends Component {
          static displayName = Patient.name;

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          }

            componentDidMount() {

                alert("fgggg");
                const { isLoading, serverError, apiData } = useFetch(
                    "/Patient/GetPatients"
                );


            }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

I want to call the useFetch, here is my useFetch:

```
            import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

        function useFetch(url){
            const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
            const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);
            const [serverError, setServerError] = useState(null);

            alert("dddd");
            useEffect(() => {
                setIsLoading(true);
                const fetchData = async () => {
                    try {
                        fetch(url)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => setApiData(data));

                        //const resp = await axios.get(url);
                        //const data = await resp?.data;

                        setIsLoading(false);
                    } catch (error) {
                        alert(error);
                        setServerError(error);
                        setIsLoading(false);
                    }
                };

                fetchData();
            }, [url]);

            return { isLoading, apiData, serverError };
        };
        export default useFetch;
```

Erro:

```
Attempted import error: 'useFetch' is not exported from '../useFetch'.
```

Can anybody advise?

### UPDATE

Thanks for the resource in the answer, but i found this https://blog.bitsrc.io/fetching-data-in-react-using-hooks-c6fdd71cb24a

and now i have changed my code to this:

```
            import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

        export default function useFetch(url, opts){
                const [response, setResponse] = useState(null)
                const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
                const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
                useEffect(() => {
                    setLoading(true)
                    fetch(url, opts)
                        .then((res) => {
                            setResponse(res.data)
                            setLoading(false)
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            setHasError(true)
                            setLoading(false)
                        })
                }, [url])
                return [response, loading, hasError]
        }
```

and

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import useFetch from "../useFetch";

        export class Patient extends Component {
          static displayName = Patient.name;

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          }

            componentDidMount() {

                alert("fgggg");
                const [ response, loading, hasError ] = useFetch("", "");


            }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

I still get this error

```
×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both.  Im not sure about the error, but I don't think you can use hooks inside class components.

Comment: Like @Hozeis pointed out: once you fix your import error you're going to be faced with another. Hooks can only be used in the body of function components. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting at the end of the file you could export when defining the function/hook.

```
export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);
  const [serverError, setServerError] = useState(null);

  alert("dddd");
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => setApiData(data));

        //const resp = await axios.get(url);
        //const data = await resp?.data;

        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
        setServerError(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { isLoading, apiData, serverError };
}
```

As well double check your import path is correct.

Good reference for when creating custom hooks and using them: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-react-hooks/

UPDATED: As Hozeis commented. You cannot use hook inside class components. Just noticed you were using a class component

Comment: Exporting when declaring the function has exactly the same effect as exporting it below by reference. Its really just a personal preference.

Comment: @BrianThompson Yeah I realized this after posting the answer that the main problems are the import error and the class component. Nothing to do with the export at all.